# How can I get this triangle next to the sentence?

Tags: math-mode

When I put this in LateX it comes up with indents at the front of each sentence, I just want the sentence like normal and then the triangle next to it.

```
\begin{gather*}
(0,0,0,1,0) \iff  
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad 4 \\
(0,0,0,1,0) + (0,1,0,-1,1) = (0,1,0,0,1) \iff  2 \qquad 5 \\
(0,1,0,0,1) + (1,-1,0,1,0) = (1,0,0,1,1) \iff  1 \qquad 4 \qquad 5 \\ 
(1,0,0,1,1) + (0,0,1,0,0) = (1,0,1,1,1) \iff         1\qquad 3 \qquad 4 \qquad 5 \\ 
(1,0,1,1,1) + (0,1,0,0,0) = (1,1,1,1,1) \iff  1\qquad 2\qquad 3\qquad 4\qquad 5 \\
\end{gather*}
```

Answer (score 1):

like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{lc}
(0,0,0,1,0)                               \iff & 4                                 \\
(0,0,0,1,0) + (0, 1,0,-1,1) = (0,1,0,0,1) \iff & 2\qquad 5                         \\
(0,1,0,0,1) + (1,-1,0, 1,0) = (1,0,0,1,1) \iff & 1\qquad 4\qquad 5                 \\
(1,0,0,1,1) + (0, 0,1, 0,0) = (1,0,1,1,1) \iff & 1\qquad 3\qquad 4\qquad 5         \\
(1,0,1,1,1) + (0, 1,0, 0,0) = (1,1,1,1,1) \iff & 1\qquad 2\qquad 3\qquad 4\qquad 5 \\
\end{array}    
\]
\end{document}
```